# Oracle Apex AJAX callback issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle Apex application.

There is a JavaScript code that calls an Ajax callback that runs a process called **AjaxTest**.

When the Ajax call is successful, it shows the result through `alert(pData)`:

```
apex.server.process(
    'AjaxTest',                         // Process or AJAX Callback name
    {x01: accessToken},                 // Parameter "x01"
    {
        success: function (pData) {     // Success Javascript
            alert(pData);               // Show the result
        },
        dataType: "text"                // Response type (here: plain text)
    }
);
```

The PL/SQL process named **AjaxTest** is:

```
declare 
   Token varchar2(32000);
   Temp number;

Begin
   Token := apex_application.g_x01;   
   Temp := 1; -- Here there is a call to a packaged function to perform some tests and return the result
   if Temp = 1 then
        Wwv_Flow_Custom_Auth_Std.Post_Login(p_uname => Email , p_session_id => v('APP_SESSION'));   
   end if ;

   htp.p('Hi !');
end;
```

The code is expected to perform some tests on the database and authenticate the user.

I kept only the things that illustrate my problem in the previous code.

The code works and authenticates the user. However, I can't get the PL/SQL result from JavaScript.

When I remove the authentication row `Wwv_Flow_Custom_Auth_Std.Post_Login`, I'm able to get Ajax result from JavaScript and `alert(pData)` works (I get "Hi !").
But when I keep this line, `alert(pData)` shows the HTML of the entire page which is not what I need (see picture below).

I need to get the exact result of the Ajax callback.

[image]

Comment: did you get the answer sir?